# Control filter options for dpkg-source via debian/control file or such?

Tags: dpkg

It turns out that the cmake source code includes some dummy test files whose names end with `.a`, which is excluded by `dpkg-source`.

I'd like to have a generic source package CI job, which I would like to keep parameter-less.

Is there any way to control the behavior of dpkg-source via some config file, or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

Add the file `debian/source/options`.

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=735377